# Automating Google Analytics Reports

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-docs, google-analytics-api, google-docs-api

We started using the Google Analytics add-on to do our daily reporting(Google Spreadsheet). Every morning, we run the program to get the previous day's data and copy n paste that data onto our the reporting spreadsheet e.g.

[image]

We are looking for a way to automate the process of transferring the data to our reporting spreadsheet(instead of using the old fashioned copy n paste).

Does anyone have any idea how we can automatically pull the Google Analytics data we run every morning onto our company's reporting spreadsheet? Everyday, the new data would need to be transferred to a row below (the next date). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just like to point out that the data isn't done processing for 24 - 48 hours you may want to double check your numbers.  Grabbing yesterdays numbers isn't usually a good idea unless you have a low traffic website.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Google Analytics API was created for.

An overview is located [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script). This tutorial will walk you through:

- enabling the Analytics API in Google Sheets (so it can talk to Analytics)
- enabling the API in Google Analytics (so it can be spoken to by Sheets)
- creating a basic script in the Sheets Script Editor
- learning where all the pieces go to pull data and push it to Sheets

You'll wind up with blocks of code that look like this:

```
 function runUpdate() {
  try {

    var firstProfile = getFirstProfile();
    var newUsers = getnewUsersForProfile(firstProfile);

  ...
  } 
}

function getnewUsersForProfile(firstProfile) {

  var profileId = firstProfile.getId();
  var tableId = 'ga:' + profileId;
  var startDate = getLastNdays(5);   // 5 days ago.
  var endDate = getLastNdays(0);     // Today.

  var optArgs = {
    'dimensions': 'ga:date',         // Comma separated list of dimensions.
  };

  // Make a request to the API.
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
      tableId,                           // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
      startDate,                         // Start-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      endDate,                           // End-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      'ga:newUsers',           // You'll have to change this for the metrics you want.
      optArgs
  );
}
```

From there, it's a simple matter of changing up the dimensions and metrics to match up with what you want to do. Bonus: the data comes out in the form of a row, so your sheet is perfectly set up for it. We have a similar project, but the dates are columns, so I had to do a little hacking to get the data to populate correctly. Yours should be much easier! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could write custom API calls as Mihir suggested. However Google Spreadsheets is, well, a spreadsheets software which means it supports references between sheets and spreadsheet files.

So in your case you could have your sheet with the add-on and a target sheet with your report and use the importrange function which, [as per documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)

> imports a range of cells from a specified spreadsheet

Something like

```
IMPORTRANGE("[[spreadsheet key]]", "sheet1!B1:B31")
```

(spreadsheet key is the alhpanumeric string from the spreadsheet url) would copy the second row into your target range.